# Stop executing further code in Java

Tags: java

I have looked in the Javadoc but couldn't find information related to this.

I want the application to stop executing a method if code in that method tells it to do so.

If that sentence was confusing, here's what I want to do in my code:

```
public void onClick(){

    if(condition == true){
        stopMethod(); //madeup code
    }
    string.setText("This string should not change if condition = true");
}
```

So if the boolean `condition` is true, the method `onClick` has to stop executing further code.

This is just an example. There are other ways for me to do what I am trying to accomplish in my application, but if this is possible, it would definitely help.

Comment: `condition = true` is an assignment expression. Watch out for the distinction.

Comment: `(condition = true)` is **always** `true`.

Comment: that's just an example. sorry for the typo. fixed it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong... but the title of question appears to be misleading... it says "Java", while description has Javascript problem to be precise. Also the tag is of Java, while it should have been of javascript

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just do:

```
public void onClick() {
    if(condition == true) {
        return;
    }
    string.setText("This string should not change if condition = true");
}
```

It's redundant to write `if(condition == true)`, just write `if(condition)` (This way, for example, you'll not write `=` by mistake).

Answer (score 20):

`return` to come out of the method execution, `break` to come out of a loop execution and `continue` to skip the rest of the current loop. In your case, just `return`, but if you are in a for loop, for example, do `break` to stop the loop or `continue` to skip to next step in the loop

Answer (score 19):

To stop executing java code just use this command:

```
    System.exit(1);
```

After this command java stops immediately!

for example:

```
    int i = 5;
    if (i == 5) {
       System.out.println("All is fine...java programm executes without problem");
    } else {
       System.out.println("ERROR occured :::: java programm has stopped!!!");
       System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: `System.exit()` will stop the entire server (tested on Tomcat) or the application.

Answer (score 8):

There are two way to stop current method/process :

1. Throwing Exception.
2. returnning the value even if it is void method.

Option : you can also kill the current thread to stop it.

For example :

```
public void onClick(){

    if(condition == true){
        return;
        <or>
        throw new YourException();
    }
    string.setText("This string should not change if condition = true");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `return` to end the method's execution

Answer (score 2):

Either `return;` from the method early, or `throw` an exception.

There is no other way to prevent further code from being executed short of exiting the process completely.

Answer (score 0):

In your thread, you need to check `Thread.interrupted()`, and if you have a flag too as some others mentioned, that'd be handy too. All based on your specific use case.

Answer (score -1):

I think just using `return;` would do the job

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18041783/2227743).