# oncomplete for p:ajax event is always called, even if the listener returns nothing

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, listener, onselect

I have a dataTable with different rows, when i select the particular rows i don't want to perform any onClick event on the particular row. I want to prevent calling show() method in oncomplete. I have tried different ways but, i am unable to stop it.

Here is my code given below.

```
<h:form id="availableBooksForm">
        <p:messages />
        <p:panel>
            <p:remoteCommand name="show" action="#{boAction.selectPromotion}" />

            <p:dataTable id="BooksTable" value="#{userProfile.availableBooks}"
                var="res" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{res.promotionId}"
                rows="#{referenceData.recordsPerPage}" lazy="true"
                resizableColumns="true" paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="#{referenceData.paginatorTemplate}"
                paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                style="margin-top: 5px; text-overflow: ellipsis;">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{boAction.onSelectPromotion}"
                    oncomplete="show()" />

                <p:column headerText="#{msg.promotionInfo}">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="pct50,"
                        style="font-size: 12px">

                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.promoCode}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{res.promoCode}">
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="#{userProfile.displayStringFormat}" />
                        </h:outputText>

                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.promoName}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{res.promoName}">
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="#{userProfile.displayStringFormat}" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
```

here i am calling the onSelectPromotion method to return nothing as shown in the below:

```
public void onSelectPromotion(SelectEvent event) {

    String selectedType = ((AllBooks) event.getObject()).getPromoType();
    if(selectedType.equals(BookType.getBookType)) {
        return;
    }
}
```

after this the show() method is calling the `boAction.selectPromotion` action. I dont want to call this method. How can i prevent this by selecting particular row from the dataTable.

I don't want to execute this method if i select the row from the table.

```
public String selectPromotion() {
    //some code is executing here
}
```

Comment: maybe try to make a selection via radiobuttons in the columns like this `<p:column selectionMode="single" />`

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 the table already existing, and when we select on each row it navigates to another page, but for some of the rows don't want to navigate to other pages based on the content in it. so i am trying to not to perform onselect event on some of the selected rows.

Answer (score 4):

Using `return` in your Ajax listener will not prevent the `oncomplete` from being called, it will just stop execution of the method. Basically your listener is useless. See:

- [Stop executing further code in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041770/stop-executing-further-code-in-java)

But you can solve your problem differently. In your `p:dataTable` use the `selection` attribute to keep a reference to the currently selected row. For example `selection="#{userProfile.selectedBook}"` (add `selectedBook` to your bean and make sure there are getters and setters). Then in the `selectPromotion` method you can simply get the `selectedBook` from your bean and decide whether you need to end or continue to process the remaining code.

You can [see the `selection` attribute in action](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) in the showcase.

Comment: if i want to end the process in the `selectPromotion` anything to be implemented differently. need some ideas.

Comment: Have not tried to change ir recently, but I always had problems using the selection attribute and access its contents in an ajax listener.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the below code snippet in the xhtml file , i am not allowing to select the row.

```
<p:dataTable id="BooksTable" value="#{userProfile.availableBooks}"
            var="res" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{res.promotionId}"
            rows="#{referenceData.recordsPerPage}" lazy="true"
            resizableColumns="true" paginator="true"
            paginatorTemplate="#{referenceData.paginatorTemplate}"
            paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
            style="margin-top: 5px; text-overflow: ellipsis;" 
            disabledSelection="#{(res.promoName == 'Your String')}">
```

by adding the disabledSelection with the condition, i am not allowing to select particular row in the dataTable using the code: `disabledSelection="#{(res.promoName == 'Your String')}"`

if you have integer type of value to compare you can use the below condition to check as 
`disabledSelection="#{(res.promoName == 123456)}"`